# is there a program that keeps me up to date on blog and forum posts?

Tags: rss, blogs, forum

I would think that this exists already, but I haven't found it yet. Is there a program/website that can keep me up to date on blog and forum posts? Say that there is a forum that I want to follow, but it hardly ever has replies... I don't want to log in every day or whatever to see what's going on.
I'm sure you can sign up for email updates, but I don't want emails.. I preferably would have it in the form of an RSS feed or something...

Comment: Well, RSS is probably the tool you want to be using. You just have ti pick a reader: newsbin, digg, feedly, the old reader... etc are all great options!

Answer (score 0):

Sure - if the forum has an RSS feed, you can subscribe to it here: http://www.specificfeeds.com/RSS-Feed-Reader

You can also filter it by keywords if you only want to receive selected information.